# ImportError: cannot import name taskqueue

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use AppEngine TaskQueue API, so I import it like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
```

The code works perfectly online. But when I try to run it locally, I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name taskqueue
```

I checked the directory of AppEngine and I didn't find the file taskqueue.py which explains the error. Is there any reason why this file isn't included in the AppEngine SDK? And is there anyway to install it locally? I wouldn't trust just copying the file to the folder, because I am sure it depends on tens of other files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) and install the current SDK.  You're using an older version.

Comment: When was taskqueue supported? I had taskqueue which I downloaded just 1-2 month(s) ago! I thought taskqueue has been supported since a long time!

Comment: The taskqueue was previously in labs, so the import path for an older version of the SDK was `google.appengine.api.labs`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution for this myself. I just downloaded the latest AppEngine SDK (version 1.4) and it has the taskqueue.